# What does the article signify in the Greek translation of Genesis 1:1?

Tags: greek, grammar, septuagint

The beginning of the Bible states:

> In the beginning, **God** created the heavens and the earth. (Genesis 1:1 ESV)
> בְּרֵאשִׁית בָּרָא **אֱלֹהִים** אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם וְאֵת הָאָֽרֶץ
>
> In the beginning **God** made the heaven and the earth. ([LXX-Genesis](https://www.biblestudytools.com/lxx/genesis/1.html) 1:1)
> ἐν ἀρχῇ ἐποίησεν **ὁ θεὸς** τὸν οὐρανὸν καὶ τὴν γῆν

Wouldn't this translation say the same thing?

> In the beginning **God** made the heaven and the earth.
> ἐν ἀρχῇ ἐποίησεν **θεὸς** τὸν οὐρανὸν καὶ τὴν γῆν

What does the translator convey by translating אֱלֹהִים as ὁ θεὸς rather than θεὸς?

Comment: Would it be safe to assume that you are unfamiliar with Greek ?

Comment: @Lucian Well I would assume ὁ θεός would mean the God just as τὸ φῶς means the light. But there does not appear to be any translator which understands ὁ θεός as such.

Comment: Not all languages possess the same type of syntax.

Comment: @RevelationLad—Please see [my answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/13380/27191) to another question.

Comment: @Lucian If a translator can convey the meaning without the article what additional meaning do they convey by adding it? For instance, does it function as a name?

Comment: No one "added" anything. Hebrew does not translate word-for-word into Greek, nor Greek into English.

Comment: @Lucian—It can, and often does, which is different from saying absolutely that it does not.

Comment: In Hebrew there is a variety of wording for signifying Deity, both singular and composite (collective or so-called 'plural') terms. In Greek the word _Theos_ has the meaning of 'Deity', meaning Deity as such - that which possesses divine nature and divine attributes. 'God' is not a name : in either Hebrew or Greek. Nor does it apply to an indivicual (as such) any more than 'humanity' applies to one, single, human personality. As to the article the Greek article refers back to a concept that has already been identified previously. The concept is identified : it is then _located_ by the article.

Comment: @DerÜbermensch: In general, it doesn't. I wrote *does not*, not *does not ever*.

Comment: The English translation isnt correct. It should read “In the beginning of God’s creating the heavens and ..”. Hebrew is a semitic language and a lot of meaning is lost by moving to any other language. The Hebrew plurality of God implies unlimited / uncountable / infinite.

Answer (score 3):

### θεὸς vs ὁ θεὸς: not so easy …

Someone here has already tried to dismiss the Question, wondering if the questioner is  fully familiar with Greek.

I will spare you all my immediate reaction, when I read the comment.

Perhaps it is more useful to say that, if a Google search with the string ["ὁ θεὸς" "θεὸς" "article" site:hermeneutics.stackexchange.com](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22%E1%BD%81+%CE%B8%CE%B5%E1%BD%B8%CF%82%22+%22%CE%B8%CE%B5%E1%BD%B8%CF%82%22+%22article%22+site%3Ahermeneutics.stackexchange.com&newwindow=1&dcr=0&biw=1920&bih=907&sxsrf=ALeKk024gbYf40ZSxgguKIHHuDirhi7ioA%3A1623176303983&ei=b7S_YK6yO8jUkwXi5bnYCw&oq=%22%E1%BD%81+%CE%B8%CE%B5%E1%BD%B8%CF%82%22+%22%CE%B8%CE%B5%E1%BD%B8%CF%82%22+%22article%22+site%3Ahermeneutics.stackexchange.com&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAw6BwgAEEcQsANQsrkcWIbmHGDH9xxoB3ACeACAAcMBiAGzBJIBAzMuMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjupYb40ojxAhVI6qQKHeJyDrsQ4dUDCA0) returns 237 hits (!!!), the question is not easy, and has never been satisfactorily answered, here at Biblical Hermeneutics.

---

My simple answer is this: the Greek determinative article ὁ, ἡ, τό, very much like the (genderless) English determinative article "the", in front of a noun, means "this one here", either expressly indicated, or obvious in context. In the case of God, ὁ θεὸς (rather than the anarthrous θεὸς) normally translates the Hebrew אֱלֹהִ֑ים (plural of אֱלוֹהַּ), when it refers to the One and Only God.

But ὁ θεὸς, when **qualified**, can (and does) in the NT refer to even to Jesus ([John 20:28](http://classic.net.bible.org/verse.php?search=John%2020:28&book=john&chapter=20&verse=28)) and even to ... Satan, ο θεος του αιωνος τουτου ("the god of this age" - [2 Cor 4:4](http://classic.net.bible.org/verse.php?search=2%20Cor%204:4&book=2%20cor&chapter=4&verse=4))

Comment: I wish every time somebody posted something on the Internet about number of Google hits, this article would pop up in front of them.  [9,000 Google hits can't be wrong - or can they?](https://www.csmonitor.com/2004/0227/p09s01-coop.html)

Comment: What a silly, superficial comment …

Comment: It's no more superficial than the notion that "number of Google hits" is a meaningful metric.

Comment: @Kyralessa Unlike your silly example, the Google string I have shown, very specific, indicates that the question about θεὸς vs ὁ θεὸς (with the article), in spite of many Q&As dedicated to it, here at Biblical Hermeneutics, never got satisfactorily answered.

Answer (score 2):

> ἐν ἀρχῇ ἐποίησεν **θεὸς** τὸν οὐρανὸν καὶ τὴν γῆν

In the beginning, **a god** made the heaven and the earth.

> ἐν ἀρχῇ ἐποίησεν **ὁ θεὸς** τὸν οὐρανὸν καὶ τὴν γῆν

In the beginning, **the god** made the heaven and the earth.
In the beginning, **God** made the heaven and the earth.

What does the article signify in the Greek translation of Genesis 1:1?

It signifies a definite god, not just any god.

Answer (score -1):

Waltke & O'Connor Biblical Hebrew page 240 says Elohim is a unique appellative that is "inherently definite."  Terms like these  are used "more or less as names."

And,

"The anarthrous form is more common in the Pentateuch."

The word is a plural form with a singular verb and as such cannot be confused with a numeric plural.

Greek has no way of duplicating this identification and is naturally articular, especially for a nominative subject.

The ο θεός is also semantically a convertible proposition that unpacks to "He being God" or "ο ων θεός."

Thus the author assumes the existence of God and does not merely assert  it.

That being said,  this is translation Greek.   I would not make any comparisons to  native idiomatic Greek.